# wakanda can't load ssjs modules

Tags: module, wakanda, ssjs

I have been trying to use the sample server side mail module, as referenced [here](http://livedoc.wakanda.org/WAF-Mail/WAF-Mail.100-965933.en.html). In the sample code the line that loads the module

> var mail = require('waf-mail/mail');

produces the following error

> desktop.core.min.js:formatted:5206 Uncaught Can't find module
>   "waf-mail/mail".o @ desktop.core.min.js:formatted:5206button1_click @
>   index.js:13(anonymous function) @ desktop.core.min.js:formatted:5875i
>   @ desktop.core.min.js:formatted:5861r.fire @
>   desktop.core.min.js:formatted:5873o @
>   desktop.core.min.js:formatted:5908l.domCallback @
>   desktop.core.min.js:formatted:5968dispatch @
>   desktop.core.min.js:formatted:1804a @
>   desktop.core.min.js:formatted:1636

This occurs in an existing solution/project & in a newly created one, I have tried other SS modules with the same result. The module directory & modules are present inside the (OSX) server package. Am I misunderstanding something fundamental here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like, you're using a Server-side module in a Client-side script.

`desktop.core.min.js` is a frontend file that cannot find the required `waf-mail/mail` module not defined here.

If you want to send a mail, you can add a requestHandler to your bootstrap and call for the SSJS script that will send your mail.

http://doc.wakanda.org/home2.en.html#/HTTP-Request-Handlers/Introduction-to-HTTP-Request-Handlers.200-803294.en.html